# Select more than 1 columns on condition

Tags: mysql

Tell please how can select 2 or more columns on condition? I trying this, but not works

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 1=1 THEN 'A', 'B'
        ELSE 'C', 'D'
    END
```

If trying select only 1 value

```
        WHEN 1=1 THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'C'
```

it works

Comment: Do you want to select `A` and `B` as column?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal It's just an example!

Comment: @ hims056 no, just strings 'A' and 'B', this for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE 'C' END,
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'B' ELSE 'D' END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write separately.

```
SELECT
  IF(1=1, 'A', 'C'),
  IF(1=1, 'B', 'D')
```